# Streaming video to rtmp with client browser

Tags: html, flash, webrtc, rtmp

it is possible to stream video from a client browser to a rtmp server?
They are looking for a viable solution does not flash

https://github.com/ahyswang/actionscript-publisher
This is good and functional, but in flash.

Do I have to use rtc web server?
There is a more practical solution

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

No. Browsers cannot stream RTMP without flash.

Comment: And a simply solution rtc to rtmp with webrtc from browser? The website younow.com stream from browser to rtmp... Thank you